# Reflexive relation and Power SET

Tags: combinatorics

The power set of set A has $32$ elements. If the total number of relations that are reflexive, is $λ^{10}$, then λ is______

My approach is as follow

A relation R is called reflexive on a set S if for all $x\in S, (x,x)\in R$

Power Set Definition
A power set is defined as the set or group of all subsets for any given set, including the empty set, which is denoted by {}, or, ϕ. A set that has 'n' elements has 2n subsets in all. For example, let Set $A = {1,2,3}$, therefore, the total number of elements in the set is 3. Therefore, there are $2^3=8$ elements in the power set.
Let us find the power set of set B.

Example Set $B = {1,2,3}$

Hence Subsets of set $B$ = {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {1,2,3}

Therefore Power set $P(B)$ = { {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {1,2,3} };

Hence $n(P(B))=2^3=8$

Now it is given that $n(P(A))=2^n=32$, hence $n=5$, therefore $n(A)=5$

How do we proceed from here

Comment: Since you are talking about two sets, $A$ and the power set of $A$, it's not clear which one are you asking for when you talk about relations. The total number of reflexive relations **on $A$**? The total number of reflexive relations **on the power set of $A$**?

Comment: You meant to write that a set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: I copied the question as it is so i am not sure but I presume that he is asking the reflexive relation of set A

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $R$ denotes a reflexive relation on $A$ then for every ordered pair $(x,y)\in A^2$ with $x\neq y$ there are two options: $$(x,y)\in R\text{ or }(x,y)\notin R$$

How many such pairs are there? And how options gives this for $R$ then?